# Codeigniter On Ubuntu Server Throws 404 when using https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have a codeigniter app I am trying to run on a ubuntu 12.04 server.
I am somewhat new to the whole ubuntu world.

Here is what I have done so far.
Basic up with SSL
when I try https://domain.com/index.html it works properly.
My CI installation is to be accessed by domain.com/live/ci_app\

When I set the `$config['base_url'] = 'https://domain.com/live/ci_app` the first page (login page) set as in the route.php file comes up properly as expected. 
However, when I log in I get a 404 error thrown.

However, when I change the base_url to `http://domain.com/live/ci_app` (with out the S) it works fine as expected.

My guesses are probably the htaccess being the culprit but I can not see what I have done wrong.

I appreciate any valuable feedback.

Below is the htaccess placed in the CI installation level.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Below is the htaccess placed in the www level. My main aim in this file is to direct all http towards https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Also, could there be anything I should check up in the apache2.conf file or the default-sites-available file?

Comment: What does your ssl_access.log say?

Comment: Hi Scott, I have added a copy of it @ http://pastebin.com/jNQMEM64. It says "112.135.39.11 - - [23/Mar/2014:01:24:40 +0000] "-" 408 137 "-" "-"" when it throws the 404 error.

Comment: 408 is a request timeout. http://bit.ly/OMlGOC

Comment: Hi scott, in the browser it throws a 404. Can this occur due to the 408? Any suggestions I can check up on? Could it be an htaccess issue? Tx